# Multiple JQuery plugins on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am wondering if there is an easy solution to this: 
I have the following JQuery plugin created several times on elements defined in a grid

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function () {

        $(this).mouseenter(function () {
           //do something for single plugin instance
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

However, how can I go about uniquely identfying which plugin instance I am triggering the mouse enter function on. With the current setup I am referencing all the instances, but I want to only trigger the mouseenter for one of them at the time.

The plugin is created like this:

```
$(".someClass").MyPlugin();
```

Comment: You have the plugin *created* several times? Or you have the same plugin attached to several elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a plugin mutiple times, that's why it's called a plugin. You just plug it in wherever you want. Take a look at the [jquery plugins authoring page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) on how to start coding a plugin. It provides some nice templates.

In your code `$(this)` is redundant, since `this` is already a jQuery object. Then, you'd want to always `return this` to maintain chainability in your plugin. You can use `$(this)` inside the `mousenter` event to reference the current element being processed by the plugin in the DOM.

Sometimes it's also useful to `return this.each()` and loop each element and do something. In this case, since you're attaching an event it doesn't help because an event works on every item in the collection of items; in this case, `this` refers to the collection on which you called the plugin:

```
$.fn.MyPlugin = function () {

    return this.mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).something();
       //do something for single plugin instance
    });

};
```

Then you'd call the plugin like so:

```
$('elements').MyPlugin();
```

Just call the plugin on the element(s) that you want and those elements will have the `mouseenter` event attached.

Answer (score 1):

what is the html where you are using the plugin?   mouseenter can be connected to an element id so instead of calling (this).mouseenter, call the div by id (i.e $("div.somediv").mouseenter(function(){  .... what you want to do ..... }

the jquery site shows an example of using multiple mouse events for nested divs.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/